# Excel - Passing a cell containing an array formula as input to a function in another cell

Tags: arrays, excel

I was wondering if in excel there was a way to do this:

- In cell A1 write an array function (e.g.`INDEX(some_array,r_n,0)` where some_array is a square NxM array and r_n is the row number, commited using Ctrl+Space+Enter)
- In cell B2 calculate the i-th percentile of array in cell A1. I would
  like to write something like `PERCENTILE.INC(A1,i/100)`, which, alas, does not work, returning the first element of the array in A1.

Currrently I'm passing the formula in A1 to percentile, but it's a bit cumbersome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how array formulas work. If you enter an array formula into a single cell (rather than a block of cells large enough to hold the whole array) then the value in that cell *isn't* an array at all, so referring to it as the "array in cell A1" is misleading at best. If you want to use the whole array -- have your array formula in a block of cells large enough to contain it.

Comment: The problem is that the array is only returning the first number in A1 and not the entire array.  Do this, Highlight five cells in a row with the first being active, put your formula and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  The first five values will be populated.

Comment: @ScottCraner Perhaps someday Excel will allow for whole arrays to be stored in single cells. It would be a powerful enhancement and would  certainly be possible for them to implement (although potentially at the cost of slower worksheet calculation).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I knew that excel array formulas worked in arrays of cells, I just hoped it had some of its amazing, unknown-to-most functionality that could do what I needed. Unluckily, for my application i need to calculate the percentile on a square range of cells, making the block of cells solution impractical. I hope MS will add this feature

Answer (score 0):

Currently there seems to exist a functionality for this, in case someone stumbles upon the same problem as I did.

Making use of the spill range functionality, you just need to append the '#' char to the address of the first cell of the spill range you want to use as part of some function, e.g. 'A1#'.